# Angular 1.5.7 ReferenceError: start0 is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing

I tested this on Angular 1.4.7 and 1.5.7, same result on both versions.
When i'm changing route with `$location.url()` and queryString parameters facing this error.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.filter = {
    keyword: "KEY",
    cats: [1,2,3]
}

var params = $httpParamSerializer($scope.filter);

$location.url("/stores/123/search?" + params);
```

**Error:**

```
ReferenceError: start0 is not defined
```

Comment: Are you certain that error is being generated from the code shown?

Comment: @Lex, Yes, it's all about $location.url()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think i get what was is for!
The problem was conflicting between `$location.url()` and `decodeURIComponent`. But don't know why!!
This is my previous code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (e, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    $location.$$absUrl = decodeURIComponent(newUrl);
    $window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

By removing that, my problem solved!